# I can not retrieve attribute of query_entities of Table_Service

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

My Query should return more than 1000 rows. But, query_entities return only 1000 rows for one query. 
So, i want to use the token retruned when the result query is more than 1000 rows to get all rows shall be returned by the query. But i cann't retrive x-ms-continuation attribute.

```
#coding:utf-8
class Use_Azure_Data:

    def __init__(self, account_name, sas_token):
        self._account_name = account_name
        self._sas_token = sas_token

    #Auth
    def _set_table_service(self):
        table_service = TableService(account_name=self._account_name, sas_token=self._sas_token)
        return(table_service)


    def Retrives_datas(self, days_before):

        before_now = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=days_before)
        now = before_now.isoformat()
        filter = "Timestamp gt datetime'" + now + "'"
        Query = self.Table_Service.query_entities('MyTable', filter = filter, timeout=None)

        if hasattr(Query, 'x-ms-continuation'):
            print("x-ms-continuation attribut for Query EXIST.")
        else:
            print("x-ms-continuation attribut for Query NOT EXIST.


    Table_Service = property(_set_table_service)


Data = Use_Azure_Data('MyAccount', 'MySASkey' )
Data.Retrives_datas(7)
```

x-ms-continuation attribut for Query EXIST.

I wante to retrive the x-ms-continutation to use it to get all rows shall be retrived by my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using latest package of [azure-cosmosdb-table](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cosmosdb-table/), you should use `marker` instead of `x-ms-continuation`.

Sample code as below:

```
table_service = TableService(account_name, account_key)
i=0
marker = None
while True:
    tasks = table_service.query_entities(table_name, data_filter,
                                         marker = marker,
                                         num_results=1000)
    for task in tasks:
      i += 1
      print(task)
    if tasks.next_marker is not None and len(tasks.next_marker) > 0:
      marker = tasks.next_marker
    else:
        break


print i
```

You can review the definition of [query_entities on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-table-python/blob/master/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure/cosmosdb/table/tableservice.py#L678):

[image]